# NoSQL database for an online marketplace

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm building an online marketplace/auction site where sellers can list their items for sale. I'm using PHP/MySQL/Javascript. I've hit a snag though when it comes to product variations. Some products such as T-shirts have many variations such as size, colour, material, other products like paper have different sizes and thicknesses. Some products have no variations. So storing all these unknown variations in MySQL is proving really tough. I've read that a better solution would be to use a schemaless NoSQL document database management system such as CouchDB or MongoDB. I also heard that PostgreSQL could handle this heterogeneous data.

So I'm wondering whether to switch to one of these dbs and if so which one or could I just store product data in NoSQL and keep other data stored in MySQL or would that be a programming headache?

I've read the differences between CouchDB and MongoDB such as Master-Master replications vs Master-Slave replication but I don't really understand that side of things. If the site grew massively which solution would be more appropriate for hosting an online marketplace: master-master or master-slave? I also read there's differences with how they handle ad hoc queries. I'll need to be able to search the db for items based on price, location, auction-end time etc as well as make product recommendations based on previous items sold or browsing behavior, so my question is basically which db would be most suitable for an online marketplace?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongodb. Because  mongodb stores all the data into objects. 
Because you think that your database will be expand in future you can easily manage it if your data stores in objects.

The powerful feature of object is that you can expand the size of object easily. You don't have to make complex relationships like in mysql.

Also master-slave feature is a powerful feature of the mongodb. 
 Here every database is copied two times. So that if any big error happens in future you can easily backup your database.

Master record contains the original copy of your database while slave contains the backup copy of your database. Each time when you insert any data into your db it will automatically copied in slave.